# Set minimum z-index to jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js, datepicker

I have case, when my datepicker and some div with buttons overlaps in wrong way.
For this case I can set manually z-Index to datepicker(for my case z-Index:3 will be fine), but this will broke other places, as z-index is calculated by library (as I know).

So I want to set minimum z-index value to datepicker or just increase z-Index.

So I add to setting object own `beforeShow` function:

```
options.beforeShow = function (input,inst ){
    inst.dpDiv.css('z-index', inst.dpDiv.css('z-index') + 2);
}
```

But this still didn't work.

Full Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NAgNV/2314/

---

P.S. I can't change z-Index of div with buttons.

Comment: You need to change the z-index for the whole datepicker element. Right now it stays at 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***ANSWER UPDATE***

The event handler *beforeShow* runs inside the *_showDatepicker* method. If you wish to overwrite an internal method I suggest to use this one instead of *_updateDatepicker*:

```
$.datepicker._showDatepicker_original = $.datepicker._showDatepicker;
   $.datepicker._showDatepicker = function(input) {
   $.datepicker._showDatepicker_original(input);
   // now change the z-index
   $.datepicker.dpDiv.css('z-index', +$.datepicker.dpDiv.css('z-index') + 2);
}
```

Now, you don't need anymore the event *beforeShow*:

The snippet:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var $el = $(element);

    //initialize datepicker with some optional options
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};


    $.datepicker._showDatepicker_original = $.datepicker._showDatepicker;
    $.datepicker._showDatepicker = function(input) {
      $.datepicker._showDatepicker_original(input);
      // now change the z-index
      console.log('Initial z-index: ' + $.datepicker.dpDiv.css('z-index'));
      $.datepicker.dpDiv.css('z-index', +$.datepicker.dpDiv.css('z-index') + 2);
      console.log('Changed z-index: ' + $.datepicker.dpDiv.css('z-index'));
    }

    $el.datepicker(options);

    //handle the field changing
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function() {
      var observable = valueAccessor();
      observable($el.datepicker("getDate"));
    });

    //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
      $el.datepicker("destroy");
    });

  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
        $el = $(element),
        current = $el.datepicker("getDate");

    if (value - current !== 0) {
      $el.datepicker("setDate", value);
    }
  }
};

var viewModel = {
  myDate: ko.observable(new Date("12/01/2013")),
  setToCurrentDate: function() {
    this.myDate(new Date());
  }
};


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
td, th { padding: 5px; border: solid 1px black; }
th { color: #666; }
a { font-size: .75em; }

.scrolled {height : 100px;}

.btn-c{z-index: 3; position : relative;}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>


<div class='scrolled'>
    <input data-bind="datepicker: myDate, datepickerOptions: { minDate: new Date() }" />
</div>
<hr />
<div class='btn-c'>


    <button data-bind="click: setToCurrentDate">Set To Current Date</button>
</div>

<hr />

<div data-bind="text: myDate"></div>
```

***OLD ANSWER***

Because on ***beforeShow***  z-index value is reset you may delay the:

```
inst.dpDiv.css('z-index', inst.dpDiv.css('z-index') + 2);
```

Your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NAgNV/2317/) and the example:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var $el = $(element);

    //initialize datepicker with some optional options
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};

    options.beforeShow = function (input,inst ){
      setTimeout(function() {
        inst.dpDiv.css('z-index', inst.dpDiv.css('z-index') + 2);
      }, 1);
    }

    $el.datepicker(options);

    //handle the field changing
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function() {
      var observable = valueAccessor();
      observable($el.datepicker("getDate"));
    });

    //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
      $el.datepicker("destroy");
    });

  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
        $el = $(element),
        current = $el.datepicker("getDate");

    if (value - current !== 0) {
      $el.datepicker("setDate", value);
    }
  }
};

var viewModel = {
  myDate: ko.observable(new Date("12/01/2013")),
  setToCurrentDate: function() {
    this.myDate(new Date());
  }
};


 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
td, th { padding: 5px; border: solid 1px black; }
th { color: #666; }
a { font-size: .75em; }

.scrolled {height : 100px;}

.btn-c{z-index: 3; position : relative;}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>


<div class='scrolled'>
    <input data-bind="datepicker: myDate, datepickerOptions: { minDate: new Date() }" />
</div>
<hr />
<div class='btn-c'>


    <button data-bind="click: setToCurrentDate">Set To Current Date</button>
</div>

<hr />

<div data-bind="text: myDate"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works :). But should I set timeout to 1 or can set 0? Looks like both cases are working...

Comment: After codeReview, teamLead suggested to avoid timeOut and use something like `afterShow`. After googling I've found https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6885 and tried to use it, but always get stackoverflow error. http://jsfiddle.net/NAgNV/2318/ example. Does this approach correct?

Comment: Now sorry for my delay... But In updated answer I get error `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. on line `$.datepicker._showDatepicker = function (input) {`

Comment: I removed the loop because the onbeforeshow event is useless. Did you copy the snippet content correctly?

Comment: I tested it on chrome and it works? Let me know more info to fix your issue.

Comment: as Snippet it works, but in my web app - not. Need to investigate more

Answer (score 0):

Simply add **!important** in your css file:

```
.ui-datepicker {z-index:4 !important;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q693qtdt/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this solution doesn't work for me. I have datepicker also in Modal and with this solution it will be hidden. This was my first idea :)